# Open dynamic file (fopen)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to open a document that users have previously uploaded to my site. From resarch I get that fopen() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php ) is a good alternative but I just don't get it. The link for a document only shows if a document has actually been uploaded before (which I have managed to do). Clicking on that link should open the file in whatever format it is (Word for doc/docx, pdf-reader for pdf etc). In this case I'm lost both when it comes to how to write this in HTML and PHP.

The last attemp I tried was this:

```
<p><a href="#" target="_blank">Word Lesson Plan</a>';
if((!empty($row["File"])))
{ echo' | <a href="'fopen($row["File"],"r");'">For Students</a>';}
echo '</p>
```

But it's not even displaying the page like that. I'm really stuck with this. How do I add a link to the file in the database dynamically and only show it if there is a file in the database?

/Håkan

Answer (score 0):

Fopen is used to open the file for reading or writing. To display the file uploaded, just add the correct file path to href attribute in anchor tag.

```
{ echo' | <a href="'.$row["File"].'">For Students</a>';}
```

Considering $row['File'] is the path of the file where it is uploaded in the server.

Comment: Yes, if I want to open for example a .doc in words it will have to be reading or/and writing. now it will only open it in the browser. Or am I completely lost?...